# Paypal smart button checkout without shipping

Tags: javascript, c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using Paypal's Smart Payment Buttons with the following code:

```
window.paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: this.price,
                    currency: "USD"
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    ...
}
```

Which works fine except for the fact that it asks the user for a shipping address on the checkout window, which I want to get rid of as this is a digital good and not a physical one. How can I achieve that? I've tried doing `no_shipping: 1` and similar to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to create a payment instead of an order in the server side using a payment experience you have previously created.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [application_context](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/?mark=order#definition-application_context) and shipping_preference like this

```
return actions.order.create({
    "application_context": {
        shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
    },
    purchase_units: [{
        amount: {value: "0.1"},
    },],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, most of the attributes of `application_context` are **DEPRECATED**, so you need to use instead `payment_source` in the following way:

```
return actions.order.create({
  purchase_units: [
    ...
  ],
  payment_source: {
    paypal: {
      experience_context: {
        shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You can see more info about `payment_source` [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-payment_source).